# A tricky question using the Second Derivative Test to show that a point is a local minimizer,

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, optimization

Suppose we are given a function $f(x)$ with two continuous derivatives which satisfies the differential equation

$xf′′(x)+3x(f′(x))^2=1−e^{−x}$ for all real x.

(Do not attempt to solve this differential equation.)

Part 1

If f has an extremum at a point c, show that this extremum is a (local) minimum. Consider the cases c≠0 and c=0 separately.

Part 2

If $f(0)=f′(0)=0$, find the smallest constant $A$ such that $f(x)≤Ax^2$ for all x≥0

I have solved Part 1 - using the standard Second Derivative Test and also utilizing L'hopital's rule and the fact that $f \in C^2$.

I sort of solved Part 2, but am not sure exactly which $A$ is the "smallest".

My work for Part (2):

Put $g(x)=Ax^2 -f(x)$.

Then we want to find the smallest $A$ such that, for every $x\ge 0 $

$$g(x)=Ax^2 -f(x)\ge 0$$

but

$$g(0) = A(0) - f(0) = 0$$

so we know that $x=0$ is a local minimizer of $g(x)$.

Then $g'(0) = 2A(0) - f'(0) = 0$

as expected, since x = 0 is an extremum / critical point.

Now, the key part is this:

$$g''(0) = 2A - f''(0) = 2A - 1$$

$f''(0)$ = 1, from calculations in Part 1.

Since we know that $x=0$ is a minimizer, then we force

$$2A-1>0$$

and this implies that we need $A > \large \frac{1}{2}$

So, if all of my work is fine, then what exactly would the "smallest" $A$ be?  Would it be exactly $\large \frac {1}{2}$? Or, something like $\large \frac{1}{2} + \epsilon$?

Thanks,